# How would I set the data source for the media player based on which button is clicked?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Im tinkering with the mediaplayer and have mp3s stored in my res/raw folder. I would like to change which mp3 is played in the mediaplayer based on which button is clicked. IE if button1 is clicked play R.raw.sound1, if button2 is clicked play R.raw.sound2 etc. I'm getting a little confused as to how I need to get the data source when the button is clicked and how to set the data source to be played in the mediaplayer. I have a switch statement for my buttons.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                //get the resource and set to R.raw.sound1
        break;
            case R.id.button2:
                //get the resource and set to R.raw.sound2
```

Now here is my mediaplayer, I would like "soundfile" to be the mp3/resource thats passed into it.

```
        if(mPlayer == null) {
            try {
                mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(SoundActivity.this, soundfile);
                    mPlayer.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            mPlayer.stop();
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer =null;

        }
    }

};
```

I want to change and set "soundfile" above to the appropriate mp3 and I'm getting lost on how to pull and set the resource if its even possible this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just do it:

```
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        soundfile = R.raw.sound1;
        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        soundfile = R.raw.sound2;
        break;
```

Comment: Thats exactly how I have it except its giving an error of "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Uri." Im getting lost on how to change it from an int to the Uri.

Comment: Took some more tinkering but got it running.